# Possible to use php tag inside query string?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have multiple values passed through a POST form (from multiple check boxes of previous page) and I stored them into an array $vals. Now I want to write a query string (in a while loop) that generates a slightly different query depending on how far in the loop it has been.

```
<?php
$vals=($_POST['selectedIDs']);
$i=0;
while($vals[$i] != NULL){
$query = "SELECT * FROM List foo WHERE foo.fooID = echo $vals[$i]";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result) echo "YES IT WORKS!";                   
$i += 1;
}?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work this way? I thought that by having double quotes for query, the

```
echo $vals[$i]
```

would generate the actual value of the current index in $vals[$i] and not the literal string? Is this what's happening? Can I not have php inside a query string that the mysql servers would accept?

lets just say i have a fooID in my server table that is '12345'. Even if I set $vals='12345' and write:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM List foo WHERE foo.fooID = $vals";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result) echo "YES IT WORKS!";
```

it still doesn't work. I guess my general question would be: is it possible to write/get values of variables in a query string, and if not, is there another way around my situation? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not be placing the un-sanitized `$_POST`ed values into a SQL query. Look into using  [paramaterized arguments and mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

You can output variables using the syntax:

```
$myVar = 'toast';
$combined = "I like $myVar";
```

However, this will not work as you would like for an array.

For an array, you'll want to look into using something like php's [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert your array into a string first.

Answer (score 1):

first of all never do queries in loop.

Second of all never use straight $_POST or $_GET or whatever client is passing in queries because you can be harmed by sql injections.[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and also [clearing data for mysql in php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

ok so how it should be done (i am saying only about first one. second one i dont know how to make it without oop ).

```
<?php
$vals=($_POST['selectedIDs']);
$vals = implode(',',$vals);
$query = "SELECT * FROM List foo WHERE foo.fooID IN ($vals)";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
     echo "YES IT WORKS!";  
     var_dump($row); //you will see all the data in one row
}
}?>
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. I understand the concern with passing client inputs as queries but the POST data that was passed through was only from a selection of options through a database generated table from a previous page. It wasn't a text box, but just a check-box that I myself then hardcoded what to pass through POST. Would that still be a concern?

Comment: yes you need to be concerned because of someone can change it with for example with firebug (not even saying about special software or scripts for that) for different kind of value then you showed as proper input for example for value DELETE * FROM TABLE users where 1=1 and then you get everything cleared in table users. if you are using only id's you can make it very simple by using 'is_int()' [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php on each id of the array

Comment: always remember that user can pass whatever POST, GET, COOKIES, SESSION or anything he want to you server. So always do validation on server side. It's just text send to to your server from client. Good tool for seeing that is live http headers for firefox [link]https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra echo in your SQL string:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM List foo WHERE foo.fooID = echo $vals[$i]";
```

It should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM List foo WHERE foo.fooID = $vals[$i]";
```

Generally, it's a BAD idea to construct SQL strings from user input. Use prepared statements instead. Check here for more info on prepared statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: maybe sprintf it instead here, but still same approach

Comment: It's not just a bad idea to splicde parameters directly into a query - it means YOU HAVE NO SECURITY. It's a bad idea to fire queries inside a loop - a better solution is to use "SELECT....foo.fooID IN (" . implode(',' array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $vals)) . ")";

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys for the advice but it turned out, my code didn't execute correctly because of a syntax error (and the extra echo statement). my original code was missing quotation marks around $vals[$i]. This is a mysql syntax mistake because it didn't accept foo.fooID=12345 but did for foo.fooID='12345'. Here is the final code that solved it

```
<?php
$vals=($_POST['selectedIDs']);
$i=0;
while($vals[$i] != NULL){
$query = "SELECT * FROM List foo WHERE foo.fooID = '$vals[$i]'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result) echo "YES IT WORKS!";                   
$i += 1;
}?>
```